How to get the Field-Weighted citation impact using Scopus API
I'm trying to use the Scopus API to get a bunch of metrics associated with a list of DOIs. I can get the number of times the article has been cited, but can't seem to find where the Field-Weighted citation impact is. Does anyone know how to get this?
